# CMD thinks 8 is greater than 65

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file similar to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752022/script-to-run-a-program-at-a-certain-cpu-load) but messing with the script a bit more I realize that the load variable in that script is a string, not an integer, so when an if statement such as

`set load=8
if "%load%" geq "65" (echo larger) else (echo lesser)`
is ran, the output would be `larger`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166704/convert-a-string-to-integer-in-a-batch-file) did not fix the issue.

I have tried doing `set /a load` and `if "%load%" gtr "65"` but neither fix the issue.

Comment: Try splitting the line after `set load=8` or perhaps by concatenating with `&` like this `"load=8" & if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `""` quotes, you're comparing strings (which really doesn't make sense with `GEQ`).
Change your code to:

```
if %load% geq 65 (echo larger) else (echo lesser)
```

Comment: Oh... wow that makes me feel dumb. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Using parentheses is a very bad idea as you will run into trouble as soon as the code is placed in a parenthesised block...

Comment: @aschipfl I guess I don't understand

Comment: `if (2) GEQ (15)` causes trouble when placed within something like `for /L %%I in (0,1,2) do (if (2) EQU (15) echo bigger)`, because the first `)` (after `2`) is considered as the closing parenthesis for the opening one at `do (`, so the command line parser gets confused...

Comment: I'm really saying not to use parentheses for this, but I'll still take that line out.

Comment: Had to take out the quote, which I think also makes my answer more original